# How to efficiently update a numpy ndarray given a list of indices

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a 4 dimensional array called new_arr. Given a list of indices, I want to update new_arr based on an old array I have stored, old_arr. I am using a for loop to do this, but it's inefficient. My code looks something like this:

```
update_indices = [(2,33,1,8), (4,9,49,50), ...] #as an example 
for index in update_indices:
    i,j,k,l = index
    new_arr[i][j][k][l] = old_arr[i][j][k][l]
```

It's taking a very long time because update_indices is large. Is there a way I can update all of the terms at once or do this more efficiently?

Comment: What's your arrays shape?

Comment: It's (57, 57, 57, 57)

Comment: The only obvious thing would be to use the `index` tuple directly.  I got ~2x speedup with `[index]` vs `[index[0]][index[1]]` for a short test.

Comment: `new_arr[index] = old_arr[index]`

Comment: For the indexing proposed in above comments to be fast, you need `update_indices` to be a Numpy array and not a pure-Python list of tuples. This means that it should be directly produced as a Numpy array (as conversions are expensive too).

Comment: Does the list `update_indices` change frequently in your application or do you perform the loop more than once for the same list `update_indices`?

Comment: Great, I will give that a try. Also update_indices is changing so I'm never performing the loop more than once for the same list

Answer (score 1):

Out of curiosity I have benchmarked the various improvements posted in the comments and found that working on flat indices is fastest.

I used the following setup:

```py
rt numpy as np

n = 57
d = 4

k = int(1e6)
dt = np.double

new_arr = np.arange(n**d, dtype=dt).reshape(d * (n,))
new_arr2 = np.arange(n**d, dtype=dt).reshape(d * (n,))
old_arr = 2*np.arange(n**d, dtype=dt).reshape(d * (n,))


update_indices = list({tuple(np.random.randint(n, size=d)) for _ in range(int(k*1.1))})[:k]
```

where `update_indices` is a list of 1e6 unique index tuples.

Using the original technique from the question

```py
%%timeit
for index in update_indices:
    i,j,k,l = index
    new_arr[i][j][k][l] = old_arr[i][j][k][l]
```

takes `1.47 s ± 19.3 ms`.

Direct tuple-indexing as suggested by @defladamouse

```py
%%timeit
for index in update_indices:
    new_arr[index] = old_arr[index]
```

indeed gives us a speedup of 2: `778 ms ± 41.8 ms`

If `update_indices` is not given but can be constructed as `ndarray` as suggested by @Jérôme Richard

```py
update_indices_array = np.array(update_indices, dtype=np.uint32)
```

(the conversion itself takes `1.34 s`) the path to much faster implementations is open.

In order to index numpy arrays by multidimensional list of locations we cannot use `update_indices_array` directly as index, but pack its columns into a tuple:

```py
%%timeit
idx = tuple(update_indices_array.T)
new_arr2[idx] = old_arr[idx]
```

Giving another speedup of roughly 9: `83.5 ms ± 1.45`

If we dont leave the computation of memory offsets to `ndarray.__getitem__`,
but compute the correspondig flat indices "by hand", we can become even faster:

```py
%%timeit
idx_weights = np.cumprod((1,) + new_arr2.shape[:0:-1])[::-1]
update_flat = update_indices_array @ idx_weights
new_arr2.ravel()[update_flat] = old_arr.ravel()[update_flat]
```

resulting in `41.6 ms ± 1.04 ms`, another factor of 2 and a cumulative speedup factor of 35 compared with the original version.
`idx_weights` is simply an off-by-one reverse-order cumulative product of the array dimensions.

I assume that this speedup of 2 comes from the fact that the memory offsets / flat indices are computed twice in `new_arr2[idx] = old_arr[idx]` and only once in `update_flat = update_indices_array @ idx_weight`.

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
idx = np.array([(2,33,1,8), (4,9,49,50), ...])
new_arr[idx[:,0],idx[:,1],idx[:,2],idx[:,3]] = old_arr[idx[:,0],idx[:,1],idx[:,2],idx[:,3]]
```

no need for a loop.

Comment: Have you checked that this does not change the semantics? From what I understand about numpy indexing this should not work.

Comment: you are right, updated my answer

Comment: but I can see you already have that one covered in your answer